# knockoutjs hello world won't run

Tags: knockout.js

I am new to Knockout, have read posts extensively, but cannot get simple example to run in Visual Studio 2015.

Always get all the html tags flagged as type or namespace problem in debugger, and when run anyways, I see empty boxes.

Here is the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title> Home Page</title>
    <script type='text/javascript' src='jquery-1.10.2.min.js'></script>
    <script type='text/javascript' src='knockout-20.3.0.debug.js'></script>
</head>
<body>
    <p>First name: <input data-bind="value: firstName" /></p>
    <p>Last name: <input data-bind="value: lastName" /></p>
    <h2>Hello, <span data-bind="text: fullName"> </span>!</h2>

<script type="text/javascript">
    // Here's my data model
    function viewModel() {
        this.firstName = ko.observable('Planet');
        this.lastName = ko.observable('Earth');
        this.fullName = ko.computed(function() {
            // Knockout tracks dependencies automatically.
            return this.firstName() + " " + this.lastName();},this);
        };

    ko.applyBindings(viewModel()); // This makes Knockout get to work
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please add more context. What is the project template you're using? How does your project/solution structure look like?

Comment: Are you sure about the knockout script version `knockout-20.3.0` ? Or should it be `knockout-2.3.0`  ?

Answer (score 1):

I checked you example it works fine, if put correct version of knockout. I put version which is older. Please check your knockout script src, I hope it will be help to you.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title> Home Page</title>
        <script type='text/javascript' src='https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js'></script>
        <script type='text/javascript' src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/2.0.0/knockout-debug.js'></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p>First name: <input data-bind="value: firstName" /></p>
        <p>Last name: <input data-bind="value: lastName" /></p>
        <h2>Hello, <span data-bind="text: fullName"> </span>!</h2>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            // Here's my data model
            function viewModel() {

                this.firstName = ko.observable('Planet');
                this.lastName = ko.observable('Earth');
                this.fullName = ko.computed(function() {
                    // Knockout tracks dependencies automatically.
                    return this.firstName() + " " + this.lastName();},this);
                };

            ko.applyBindings(new viewModel());
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Just to clarify in the OP the viewModel isn't called with the new operator